# Почему в наследнике Application метод принимает Context

Tags: java, android

Попался такой вот код с [гитхаб](https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/frogermcs/io/githubclient/GithubClientApplication.java)

```
    public class GithubClientApplication extends Application {
    
    
    
    public static GithubClientApplication get(Context context) {
        return (GithubClientApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
   }
```

Не раз уже попадался подобный код, когда в наследнике `Application`, метод принимает на вход контекст и вот таким вот способом делает приведение этого контекста к типу класса.

 Зачем этому классу нужен контекст? у него ведь итак есть свой или эти контексты чем то отличаются? Зачастую такой момент вызывается из класса наследника `Activity`. Я так предположил, что аргумент контекст нужен, чтобы только класс, имеющий доступ к контексту, мог получить экземпляр класса наследующего `Application`.

Так же видел код, где в методе передается контекст из одного класса расширяющего `Activity`  в другой класс расширяющий `Activity`

Comment: Это не конструктор, utility method. Просто помогает краткой записью получить GithubClientApplication из любого контекста.

Comment: точно..что то уставший не доглядел, что метод гет называется..длинное название класса взяло на себя акцент)

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: Последний абзац: нет кода, нет комментариев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я уже по сути в комментарии ответил, но раз вы настаиваете :), напишу более развернуто.

- Это `utility method`, т.е. вспомогательный, который помогает делать код компактнее, проще и более читаемым. Обычно такие методы выносят в пакеты или классы с названием `Utils` или еще как. Но тут автор решил поместить его в подкласс `Application`, что собственно логично, но не принципиально.
- Это статический метод, поэтому никакого доступа к контексту у него нет. Вот контекст и передается через параметр. И этот контекст самому классу не нужен, как вы пишете, он нужен только этому методу.